# pygameでの画像コントラストの設定

Tags: python3, windows-10, pygame

私は現在Pygameでのとあるゲームを制作しています。
その過程でゲーム内で使用する画像のコントラストを
設定した値に変更したいと考えています。
なにか良い方法は無いか教えていただきたく思います。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: おそらくこの辺の記事を基に探っていくのだと思われます。[Algorithms for Adjusting Brightness and Contrast of an Image](https://ie.nitk.ac.in/blog/2020/01/19/algorithms-for-adjusting-brightness-and-contrast-of-an-image/), [画像処理アルゴリズムパート5：コントラスト調整](https://www.dfstudios.co.uk/articles/programming/image-programming-algorithms/image-processing-algorithms-part-5-contrast-adjustment/) あと題名にあるように、コントラストは設定では無く調整するものでは？ あるいは例えば結果としてある範囲に収まるようする、その範囲を指定するといった考え方なのかもしれませんが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。参考にした結果、解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 可能ならばどのような処理を行ったのかソースコード付きで自己回答してもらえると、情報共有が出来るのでお願いします。